# Why is there a color added to my UINavigationBar background?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have no idea why this is happening and it just started happening even though I haven't changed that code recently.  I'm using a normal UINavigationBar with the barTint set to white, and the tintColor set to standard blue.

[image: View Hierarchy Debug showing problem]

I present this navigation controller modally.  For some reason, when inspecting the view hierarchy, the UINavigationBar has:

`UINavigationBar
-_UINavigationBarBackground
--UIImageView`

This image view, upon inspection in the debugger, has a backgroundColor set to `[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha: 0.3]`

Why?  I have no idea what's gone wrong.

Happening in the simulator.

Has anyone ever seen this?  Insane!

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out why this is, but like a bad doctor I found a way to make the symptom go away without knowing what the problem is.

I subclassed UINavigationBar and did some hacking on layoutSubviews:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UIView *subview = self.subviews[0];
    if ([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) hasPrefix:@"_"]) {
        subview = subview.subviews[0];
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            subview.backgroundColor = nil;
        }
    }
}
```